# ...все(,) как мухи(,) выздоравливают

Tags: пунктуация

Объясните, пожалуйста, пунктуацию: вообще и конкретно у Гоголя. 
У Гоголя всё без запятых - и вроде бы логично.
*Но вопрос вызван к жизни тем, что процитировал было (по совершенно постороннему поводу) эту реплику - и только потом обнаружил, что по сети гуляет аж три варианта.*

Answer (score 3):

***Аппликация*** всегда изменяет содержание и структуру известного выражения, поэтому появляются основания для постановки знаков. В выражении ***как мухи выздоравливают*** запятые можно ставить и не ставить - по желанию автора. Я бы не поставила, так как фразеологизм-основа очень хорошо известен всем и аппликация воспринимается тоже как фразеологизм.

Comment: А что такое аппликация в данном случае? И как Вам вариант с одной запятой? ("все как мухи, выздоравливают")? С подачи Википедии иенно он пошел гулять по сети.

Comment: Аппликация здесь замена слова "мрут" на "выздоравливают". С одной запятой фраза тоже имеет право на существование, но смысл немного меняется. Все как мухи - грамматическая основа, в которой подразумевается уподобление всех мухам. А потом эти "все как мухи" выздоравливают.

Comment: Я что-то не сталкивался с подобным значением. Самое ближнее, что вспомнилось - **антифразис**. А аппликация - это наложение **звуков**. Нет? Впрочем, ладно. По сути я ничего возразить не могу.

Comment: Посмотрите, пожалуйста, здесь: http://stihi.pro/1360-citirovanie.html

Comment: Ага, спасибо. Забавно, Гаспаров такого не знает, а Скорик вот узнала. Теперь и я знаю, кто такая Скорик))).

Answer (score 1):

**Существуют фразеологизм: мрут (или дохнут) как мухи** - умирают в большом количестве. Например: "Если бы арестанты лишены были всякой возможности иметь свои деньги — они или сходили бы с ума, или **мёрли как мухи**". (Достоевский).

У Гоголя **скопирован этот фразеологизм с заменой одного слова**, что и создает комический эффект: "С тех пор, как я принял начальство, - может быть, вам покажется даже невероятным, - **все как мухи выздоравливают**". Здесь оборот точно вписывается в структуру предложения в значении наречия  "очень быстро" (по Хлестакову), произношение без пауз, обособления нет.

Когда же идет **пересказ текста**, то  оборот начинают обособлять по обычным правилам, например: "Кто в комедии так выражался: «У меня все больные, как мухи, выздоравливают!»?".  Меняется структура предложения, произвольно расставляются акценты, поэтому и ставятся запятые.